# Consuming WCF service over https

Tags: wcf, authentication, https, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I need to consume a web service exposed through a https connection, this service is managed by a client who gave me the certificate (.pfx) and is password, so I need to call an operation on this service however I having some problems when try it.

Maybe I'm not properly create the ssl connection between client and service, I will show my web.config and a piece of code where call the service

`web.config`:

```
  <configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="credentialConfiguration">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate 
                      findValue="10 14 08 f4 00 00 00 00 0f 3f"
                      storeLocation="CurrentUser"
                      x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber"/>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="myBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa:700/aaa/aa/"
                behaviorConfiguration="credentialConfiguration"
                binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="myBinding"
                contract="mydll.service"
                name="faturasSOAP" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Code where call the service :

```
    //Create authentication header 
        CdoHeaderCredentials header = GetEncryptedCredentials();

        //Client Proxy 
        InvoiceService.faturasClient clientProxy = new faturasClient();

        //Custom header 
         AddWseSecurityHeaderEndpointBehavior customEndpointBehavior =
            new AddWseSecurityHeaderEndpointBehavior(header.Username, header.Password, header.Nonce, header.ClientDate);
                clientProxy.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(customEndpointBehavior);

         //get document to register on service
         RegisterInvoiceType documentToSnyc = manager.DocumentToSnyc();

         //Load private certificate with key
         X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(
          certPath,
            _certKey,
            X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

         //Link the certificate with the proxy
         clientProxy.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;

            //invoke operation
        RegisterInvoiceResponse response =  clientProxy.RegisterInvoice(new RegisterInvoiceRequest(documentToSnyc));
```

Whenever I call the service the response is the same :

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <s:Header xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" />
  <env:Body>
    <env:Fault>
      <env:Code>
        <env:Value>
env:Receiver</env:Value>
      </env:Code>
      <env:Reason>
        <env:Text xml:lang="en-US">
Internal Error (from server)
</env:Text>
      </env:Reason>
    </env:Fault>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

My question is if this error is about the client authentication throw ssl, or is anything else?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information here to determine why you're seeing the error without knowing anything about the server, but since the error text says "Internal Error (from server)" my guess is that it has nothing to do with anything you're doing on the client-side. In any case, once you see something like this, you should probably contact the owner of the web service for help - if it's an "internal error", it should be their responsibility to either debug it or to tell you what actual error on your side this "internal error" represents.

Comment: Thanks for response, I'am having doubts because to authenticate requests some parameters must be encrypted,the problem is I do not know if the error comes from this encrypted parameters, however my client has established codes of erros for these situations, eg (8 - public key invalid, 9 - password not filled ,11- symmetric key invalid). As you can see none of these code is returned